# Array declaration for Java Primitive types?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why this is the way in which Java defines the array type for its primitive data types, for example:

```
int b[] = new int[100];
```

Since b is type of primitive type (in this case integer), how would variable `b` hold the reference which get returned by `new` operator?

Can anyone help me clarify this?

Comment: `b` is not a primitive. Any array is an object, even if its data type is primitive.

Comment: ^^ `b` contains an object reference (the array). `b[0]` is a primitive (an `int` within the array object).

Comment: @BackSlash: If it is an object, then why can't we use like this: int b[] = new int[200]() (the constructor?)

Comment: @CuriousMind Because the Java syntax doesn't allow that. This is the way programmers designed the language.

Comment: @CuriousMind Because an array doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: Hmm, got is, so essentially b in this case is Object, and b[0], b[1] ... are the primitive data types, and not b itself.

Comment: *BTW:* It might be more clear to you if you use the recommended syntax `int[] b =` instead of the discouraged C-compatible syntax `int b[] =`. This highlights the fact that the *type* of `b` is `int[]`.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks so much for this info, I would stick to recommended syntax.